# Added two inline-block gif images, background color changes on that line?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

```
html{
    background-color:#739AC5;
}

img{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#739AC5;
    background-color:#739AC5;
    margin:0px;
}
```

I added two inline-block gif images. However, after I add them, the background color changes from a light blue to white but only on that line. I've added color and background-color properties to image but nothing changes. If I remove the images from my HTML, the background-color returns to normal. I searched somewhere to change line-height:0; but this did not work for me either.
Any ideas as to what is going on? I might add I am using bootstrap but I linked my stylesheet last.

Comment: looks fine from here => http://jsfiddle.net/D9YN7/ ....please show your html markup and any other relevant css....

Comment: Are the images being used PNG or some other format that doesn't support transparency?

Comment: @Paulie_D the images are .gif files and they are transparent

Comment: Yeah...we need to see it in action then. JSFiddle please.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to reproduce the error... could it be an issue with the images after all?

Comment: @LifeinHD : browser-cache issue may be :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I'm almost positive it's something to do with bootstrap... I removed the link to the bootstrap.css file and the background appeared as normal...

Comment: @LifeinHD : you should have mentioned BS earlier...yes...it might conflict with your custom css style as you have given general `img` tag, instaed use `img.some_class` :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a more specific selector for `img` elements, such as:

```
div img { background-color: #fff; display: block; }
```

This selector overrides the other one since specificity trumps the cascade.